# kNN (confusion_matrix & classification_report)

Tags: python, knn

**Im trying to get the confusion_matrix & classification_report for a range of k values **

```
confusion_matrix = {}
classification_report = {}
neighbors = np.arange(5, 20)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,
random_state=42, stratify=y)
for neighbor in neighbors:    
    # Set up a KNN Classifier
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=neighbor)    
    # Fit the model
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train) 
     # Compute 
    y_pred= knn.predict(X_test) 
    confusion_matrix[neighbor] = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
    classification_report[neighbor] = classification_report(y_test,y_pred)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

**I was expecting something like a list of all reports **

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/92/5m7b39tj1j5g7s50bvjdxglc0000gp/T/ipykernel_12129/985428575.py in <module>
     13      # Compute
     14     y_pred= knn.predict(X_test)
---> 15     confusion_matrix[neighbor] = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
     16     classification_report[neighbor] = classification_report(y_test,y_pred)
     17 

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Is `confusion_matrix` a function in your program? It appears you've used the same name for a function and a dictionary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.